# Get maximum element of std::vector with strides

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, max, stride

I have a `std::vector<float>` with the following layout of data

```
x1 | y1 | z1 | x2 | y2 | z2 | .... | xn | yn | zn
```

I'm trying to figure out an STL-ish way to get the maximum `x` element as well as `y` or `z`

The obvious

```
double xyzmax = *std::max_element(myvector.begin(),myvector.end() );
```

picks the absolute maximum and does not allow me to specify the stride.
Is there some trick with no for loops?

Comment: Why can't you use loops?

Comment: Instead of using normal iterators you could use skip iterators, that jump not one but three elements on incrementing.

Comment: The trouble with the STL functions like these, is they are fine in simple cases but when you want to do something more complicated (as often happens in a real project), you have to write loops again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reference implementation of `std::max_element`.

```
template<class ForwardIt>
ForwardIt max_element(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
{
    if (first == last) {
        return last;
    }
    ForwardIt largest = first;
    ++first;
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (*largest < *first) {
            largest = first;
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

You can create your own algorithm by modifying this in the following way:

```
template<class ForwardIt>
ForwardIt max_element_nth(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, int n)
{
    if (first == last) {
        return last;
    }
    ForwardIt largest = first;
    first += n;
    for (; first < last; first += n) {
        if (*largest < *first) {
            largest = first;
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Of course it has the limitation of working only with random access iterators, but it certainly works for `vector`.

```
double xmax = *max_element_nth(myvector.begin(),myvector.end(), 3);
double ymax = *max_element_nth(myvector.begin()+1,myvector.end(), 3);
double zmax = *max_element_nth(myvector.begin()+2,myvector.end(), 3);
```

But I'd rather do it by storing the (x, y, z) values in a structure, and take a vector of that. Then, you can use the standard `max_element` with a custom comparator.

Comment: ah, but now I want also `min_element`, and `accumulate` and `find` etc. Are you going to port them all?

Comment: Cool! This is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @linello great if this answer works for you, but be aware that it will not scale if you every want to use another algorithm. Algorithms are much harder to modify than it is to set up an adaptor for the iterators.

Comment: I won't down vote a nice answer like this, but somewhere in the OP was 'no for loops'.

Comment: @hetepeperfan I guess the idea behind this answer is to wrap the redefined `max_element` in a seperate namespace `strided` so it can be used like `std::max_element`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html#iterator-facade-and-adaptor) library and the [boost::iterator_facade](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html) to create a **strided iterator** that can be initalized with a `std::vector<float>::iterator` and for which `++it` does `it += 3;` on the underlying iterator.

Given such an iterator of type `StrideIt`, you could write

```
maxX = *std::max_element(StrideIt(v.begin() + 0), StrideIt(v.end() - 2));
maxY = *std::max_element(StrideIt(v.begin() + 1), StrideIt(v.end() - 1));
maxZ = *std::max_element(StrideIt(v.begin() + 2), StrideIt(v.end() - 0));
```

This is preferably to redefining the algorithms because there are many more algorithms than iterator types.

If you want maximum flexibility, you could make `StrideIt` a class template taking the type (`float` in  your case) and a runtime construtor argument defining the stride (3 in your case).